# PHP send multiple api requests at once

Tags: php, api

i'm trying to make multiple API calls at once and get data needed from each of them, how can i do it? i want to send about 100 requests at once and grab data from them.

this is the code i currently have:

```php
<?php

$min = 7960265729;
$max = 9080098567;
$count = 0;

for($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    try{
        $r = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=EA08B4B2B515A4BAB3D742627CDCC492&steamids=7656119$i"), true);
        $avatar = $r['response']['players'][0]['avatar'];
        $profile = $r['response']['players'][0]['profileurl'];
        if($avatar != null) {
            $count += 1;
            print_r("[$count][$i] $profile \n");
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable $t){
        continue;
    }
}

?>
```

this makes one api request at a time. how can i change so it can make 100?

thanks.

Comment: if you plan to use guzzle then you can send asynchronous request at the rate of 3-5 concurrently

Comment: can i make 100 requests at once with that?

Comment: though it is possible but it may lead to slowing down or deadlock(program gets hanged), so at a time 5 is recommended though it will send 5 requests then not wait for response & then send again 5 response & so on

Comment: i managed to implement curl multi in the code. i can now send 1000 or even 2000 requests at once and get data from each of them. now i'm trying to run my script in multiprocessing

Answer (score 3):

If you have the curl extension installed, you can use [`curl_multi_exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php). What might be easier though is using a dedicated HTTP client library for this, e.g. [Symfony HttpClient](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#concurrent-requests) or [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests).

Please be aware that most APIs don't like it when you spam them with requests, especially if you want to iterate over some ids. If you don't abide by their rules you might get your API access revoked or get rate limited.

Comment: it's okay. i'm aware of the limits. i tried using curl but how can i control how many api calls i want to make? or how do i even implement it in my code?

Comment: You can control the number of connections using [`curl_multi_setopt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-setopt.php). You'll probably want to use `CURLMOPT_MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS`. HTTP client libraries will probably make things easier, especially if the API supports newer HTTP protocols, e.g. multiplexing from HTTP/2 as they will likely pick the best available option for you automatically or at least with fewer config.